# Pandas IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds, with strange manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Hi I am trying to get a sql query output in a format to keep the file stats.

I am checking if sql query has all  the dates or not. If not adding a dataframe with date and zero values and then doing the concating them into one.

df.iloc[0,1] prints the value 2018-07-02 but when checking in if statement, it returns error 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds':

Please help.

```
    import ibm_db
    import ibm_db_dbi
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd

    con = ibm_db.pconnect("DATABASE=####;HOSTNAME=####;PORT=####;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=#####;PWD=#######;","","")

    conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(con)

    today = datetime.date.today()

    today1 = today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    today2 = today1 - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    today3 = today2 - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    today4 = today3 - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    today5 = today4 - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)


    DT1 = today5.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    DT2 = today4.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    DT3 = today3.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    DT4 = today2.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    DT5 = today1.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    sql1 = "select substr(load_date,0,10) load_date, count (distinct file_name) file_count, count(1) record_count from ###### where load_date  BETWEEN '" + today5.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +" 00:00:00' and '" + today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " 23:59:59' group by substr(load_date,0,10)  ORDER BY substr(load_date,0,10) WITH UR"

    df1 = pd.read_sql(sql1, conn)

    #print df1

    df1t = df1.T

    df = df1t

    #print df1t[0]

    #index_list = df1t[(df1t.iloc[0,0] == today2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") )].index.tolist()

    #print today2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    #print list(df1t)

    df1t.columns = df1t.iloc[0] 

    df1t = df1t.drop(df1t.index[0])

    df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])

    #print df

    if df1t.iloc[0,0] != today5.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
        print("Mismatch Found For " + today5.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        dfDT5 = pd.DataFrame([today5.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),0,0], index=['LOAD_DATE', 'FILE_COUNT', 'RECORD_COUNT'])
        dfDT5.columns = [today5.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
        dfc = pd.concat([dfDT5, df], axis=1, sort=False)
        print "-------------------"
        print dfc
        #print dfDT5
        print "-------------------"
        #df1t.add(dfDT5, fill_value=0)
        print dfc.iloc[0,1]
        print "-------------------"
    if df1t.iloc[0,1] != today4.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
        print("Mismatch Found For " + today4.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The Error I am getting is below with the output:

```
    Mismatch Found For 2018-06-27
    -------------------
                  2018-06-27  2018-07-02
    LOAD_DATE     2018-06-27  2018-07-02
    FILE_COUNT             0           2
    RECORD_COUNT           0     8100999
    -------------------
    2018-07-02
    -------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\AIR_CS5.py", line 113, in <module>
        if df1t.iloc[0,1] != today4.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_tuple(key)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2013, in _getitem_tuple
        self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 222, in _has_valid_tuple
        self._validate_key(k, i)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1957, in _validate_key
        self._validate_integer(key, axis)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2009, in _validate_integer
        raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
    IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe `df1t` has only one column. Therefore, slicing `df1t.iloc[0,1]` will fail with `IndexError`.

Make sure your dataframe has the data you require for your logic, or change your logic to accommodate your data.

The line `print dfc.iloc[0,1]`, which outputs `2018-07-02`, does not represent `df1t`. It may help to print `df1t` beforehand to see what you're working with.

Comment: I got a workaround by storing dfc.iloc[0,1] in a variable